# Play 2 - How to set default value of template's parameter from Java controller?

Tags: java, templates, parameters, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to define optional parameter when rendering an scala template in Play Framework 2?

My controller looks like this:

```
public static Result recoverPassword() {
    Form<RecoveryForm> resetForm = form(RecoveryForm.class);
    return ok(recover.render(resetForm));
    // On success I'd like to pass an optional parameter:
    // return ok(recover.render(resetForm, true));
}
```

My Scala template looks like this:

```
@(resetForm: Form[controllers.Account.RecoveryForm], success:Boolean = false)
```

Also tried:

```
@(resetForm: Form[controllers.Account.RecoveryForm]) (success:Boolean = false)
```

In both cases i got "error: method render in class recover cannot be applied to given types;"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Java controller you can't omit assignation of the value (in Scala controller or other template it will work), the fastest and cleanest solution in this situation is assignation every time with default value, ie:

```
public static Result recoverPassword() {
    Form<RecoveryForm> resetForm = form(RecoveryForm.class);

    if (!successfullPaswordChange){
        return badRequest(recover.render(resetForm, false));
    }

    return ok(recover.render(resetForm, true));
}
```

Scala template can stay unchanged, as Scala controllers and other templates which can call the template will respect the default value if not given there.

BTW: as you can see, you should use proper methods for returning results from Play's `actions`, see `ok()` vs `badRequest()` also: `forrbiden()`, `notFound()`, etc, etc

You can also use [flash scope](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaSessionFlash) for populating messages and use `redirect()` to main page after successful password change, then you can just check if flash message exists and display it:

```
public static Result recoverPassword() {
    ...
    if (!successfullPaswordChange){
        return badRequest(recover.render(resetForm, false));
    }

    flash("passchange.succces", "Your password was reseted, check your mail");
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

in ANY template:

```
@if(flash.containsKey("passchange.succces")) {
    <div class="alert-message warning">
        <strong>Done!</strong> @flash.get("passchange.succces")
    </div>
}
```

(this snippet is copied from Computer Database sample for Java, so you can check it on your own disk)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The success var indicates that an email has been sent to the user and in my template I render a success message instead of showing the password reset form again. Should I do this with the help of a success-var and an if-construct in the template or should I better use two different template files?

Comment: It depends on that how sophisticated both templates are, if they are just a simple containers with form or message using one `view` will be OK.

Comment: Ok, then I'll continue with one view. Thanks again.

Comment: @joafeldmann : consider also `flash scope` + `redirect()` scenario. In that case you can just render `recover` view with full form without need, to  pass `success` param at all.

Comment: thanks for your hint, but I dont want to have the form visible after the user submitted it.

Comment: Therefore there is an redirect on the end :) The workflow is such: if there is an error, the user will see password change form again, otherwise he will see main page (`Application.index()`) with additional info, that change of the password was successful

Comment: Ah, ok ;) I'll think about that solution.